# File cannot be created in my PHP code

Tags: php

I am trying to debug the following PHP file, which is used to serve the check in request from the mobile application, so I cannot use print out to check the flow of the program, therefore I would like to create some files, so I can know how the programme is running. But I have no idea where no file is being created, even I have successfully inserted the record into the database, can anyone give help to me

Here is my PHP code:

```
$_Type = $_POST['Type'];
$_ClientID = $_POST['ClientID'];
$_TechID = $_POST['TechID'];
$_SiteID = $_POST['SiteID'];

$content = "First check"; 
$fp = fopen("C:/xampp/htdocs/Me/checking.txt","wb"); 
fwrite($fp,$content); 
fclose($fp);

function checkin($DB, $TechID, $ClientID, $SiteID){
    $dbConnection = mysql_connect($DB['server'], $DB['loginName'], $DB['password']);
    if(!$dbConnection){
        die('Error! ' . mysql_error());
        }
    mysql_select_db($DB['database'], $dbConnection);

    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Log") or die('Error! ' . mysql_error());
    $query = "SELECT `Type` FROM `Log` WHERE `TechID` = '".$TechID."' ORDER BY LogTime DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query) or die('Error! ' . mysql_error());
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
        $count = $row1['COUNT(*)'];
        if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0){
            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
                if(trim($row2['Type'])!="Checkin"){
                    $count = $count+1;
                    $timezone = "Asia/Hong_Kong";
                    if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) 
                        date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
                    $Time = date('Y/m/d H:i');

                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Log (LogID, TechID, ClientID, SiteID, LogTime, Type)
                                VALUES (".$count.", '".$TechID."', ".$ClientID.", ".$SiteID.", '".$Time."', 'Checkin')");
                }else{
                    mail('me@gmail.com', 'Test mail', 'If you can read this, everything was fine!');

                    $content1 = "First 1"; 
                    $fp1 = fopen("C:/xampp/htdocs/Me/checking1.txt","wb"); 
                    fwrite($fp1,$content1); 
                    fclose($fp1);
                }
            }
        }else{
            $count = $count+1;
            $timezone = "Asia/Hong_Kong";
            if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) 
                date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
            $Time = date('Y/m/d H:i');
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Log` (`LogID`, `TechID`, `ClientID`, `SiteID`, `LogTime`, `Type`)
                        VALUES (".$count.", '".$TechID."', ".$ClientID.", ".$SiteID.", '".$Time."', 'Checkin')");
        }
    }
}

checkin($DB, $_TechID, $_ClientID, $_SiteID);
```

As you can see, this is a program used to insert the check in record, but if person want to check in again before he has checked out, a file checking1.txt should be created. However, none of the checking.txt or checking1.txt is created after the execution.

Comment: Check your error log. Is it telling you anything? The most common reason for this is that the script doesn't have permission to create files in the directory in question (for some reason, fopen may give you a "file already exists" error in this case).

Comment: sorry to ask, as I am a beginner of PHP, may I ask where can I find the error log of PHP. Do I need to make use of the error_log() function to create the file?

Comment: logs are generally here /var/log/httpd/error_log for Linux and for windows it will depend what LAMP you are using. like wamp, xampp, zend server etc

Comment: I have checked the error log in the PHP folder, however, I cannot see any error related to execution of this check in file, it seems everything executing correctly. Moreover, as I have mentioned, it will not insert one more record if user has not checked out, the program should have gone into the else block, however, it does not send the mail also, so I have no idea how the program is running now. What I know only is it can insert the record if user has not checked in before.

Comment: Run phpinfo() and search for `error_log`. If that line is present, it will show you the location of your error log. If it's not present, then search for "loaded configuration file" to find the location of your php.ini file, and turn it on there. It's really worth the effort -- debugging PHP without error output is like groping around in a pitch-black room.